# How to Configure Eclipse Content Assist so that it will suggest JavaFX components first?

Tags: eclipse, javafx

I am using Eclipse to develop a JavaFX application. Whenever i press `Ctrl + Space`, Eclipse would suggest me components from AWT or Swing rather than from JavaFX. It happens also to `List` where instead of the `java.util.List`, it gives the `List` from other absurd modules. It doesn't also seem to learn my usage.

How can I configure my content assist preferences?

UPDATE:
Using
jdk1.8.0_101,
Eclipse Photon,
Windows

Comment: Which _Eclipse_ version are you using? What JDK version are you using? What platform are you on?

Comment: @Abra Using jdk1.8.0_101, Eclipse Photon, Windows

Comment: Are you familiar with _Content Assist_ preferences for _Eclipse_?

Comment: Filter AWT and Swing types in _Window > Preferences: Java > Appearance > Type Filters_.